# getting the value of one combobox and creating another combobox

Tags: jquery, combobox, append

I'm trying to create one combobox dynamically...but I'm failing in something...
When I select one option of the first combobox, nothing happens :(

This is the code:

```
$("#listing_status").change(function () {
        $valor = $(this).val();
        if( $valor == 'offer' ){
            alert('Fuerteventura');
            $("form tr:nth-child(4)").append('<tr><td align="right">Localidad </td><td><select id="listing_municipiosFuerteventura" name="listing_municipiosFuerteventura" class="inputbox" size="1" style="width: 115px">
    <option value="Todos">Todos</option>
    <option value="Ajuy">Ajuy</option>
    <option value="Antigua (Fuerteventura)">Antigua (Fuerteventura)</option>
    <option value="Betancuria">Betancuria</option>
    <option value="Corralejo (La Oliva)">Corralejo (La Oliva)</option>
    <option value="Gran Tarajal">Gran Tarajal</option>
    <option value="Guisguey">Guisguey</option>
    <option value="La Oliva">La Oliva</option>
    <option value="Pajara">Pajara</option>
    <option value="Puerto del Rosario">Puerto del Rosario</option>
    <option value="Tuineje">Tuineje</option>
</select>
</td></tr>');
        }else if( $valor == 'contract' ){
            alert('Lanzarote');
        }
    });
```

I use jQuery for work with this. Best regards, Daniel

Answer (score 0):

when `append()` is used there should be no whitespace between the to-be-appended markup, also if `#listing_status` is generated dynamically you should delegate the event, try the following:

```
$("form").on('change', '#listing_status', function () {
        $valor = $(this).val();
        if ($valor == 'offer'){
            alert('Fuerteventura');
            $("form tr:nth-child(4)").append('<tr><td align="right">Localidad </td><td><select id="listing_municipiosFuerteventura" name="listing_municipiosFuerteventura" class="inputbox" size="1" style="width: 115px"><option value="Todos">Todos</option><option value="Ajuy">Ajuy</option><option value="Antigua (Fuerteventura)">Antigua (Fuerteventura)</option><option value="Betancuria">Betancuria</option><option value="Corralejo (La Oliva)">Corralejo (La Oliva)</option><option value="Gran Tarajal">Gran Tarajal</option><option value="Guisguey">Guisguey</option><option value="La Oliva">La Oliva</option><option value="Pajara">Pajara</option><option value="Puerto del Rosario">Puerto del Rosario</option><option value="Tuineje">Tuineje</option></select></td></tr>');
        } else if($valor == 'contract'){
            alert('Lanzarote');
        }
});
```